# What is the fastest method to determine version of an IP address in string representation

Tags: python, optimization, ip

I am using python and I need to determine version of a given IP address in string representation. I need to repeat this a lot of times, so I want to do it as fast as possible (i.e. without creating IpAddress object and taking .version).

I know that the given string is valid and represents an IP address.

For now I am considering:

```
if ipstring[1] == '.' or ipstring[2] == '.' or ipstring[3] == '.':
    version = 4
else:
    version = 6
```

Is there any faster way that I am overlooking? As soon as IPv6 becomes more common I could flip to checking for v6 first by:

```
if ipstring[1] == ':' or ipstring[2] == ':':
    version = 6
else:
    version = 4
```

Are there any other fast methods than the one listed here?

Comment: How about you are using the `timeit` module to best their speeds?

Comment: I know the speed of this method. I am interested if there are other, faster methods.

Answer (score 1):

As different versions of IP-addresses use different separators in their representations (namely, `"."` and `":"`), and you're sure that the strings represent valid addresses, you could do:

```
if "." in ipstring: 
    version = 4
else:
    version = 6
```